# Step into when opening another workbook

Tags: vba, debugging, excel, step-into

I'm trying to debug code using "Step into", but first part of my code requires another workbook to be opened by TextBox. So "Step Into" just stops when TextBox appears (I mean that there is no opportunity to choose file via button or fill by keyboard).
Is there another way to debug code step-by-step or way to avoid this stuff?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (temporarily) add code to cause a break

```
Debug.Assert <Some Condition that returns FALSE when you want to break>
```

eg

```
Debug.Assert False
```